# Iframe content empty in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Info before reading: this code is written in vanilla js / jquery.

I have a page with a product list with infinite products and I want to scroll a bit down, click a product, go to that product detail page and when I click the browser back button it sends me to the list page at the same height where I was scrolling. So basically a pain to set up without a framework to keep track of state.

I've managed to get a POC for this appending an iframe with the product details content page and place it "on top" of the page. This, however, does not work in Firefox. Does anyone have any idea why?

I thought it was a z-index issue, however the iframe's body is empty. This is the iframe in Firefox:

```
<iframe id="productDetails" class="ProductDetailsFrame js-product-details-frame" src="http://localhost:3000/ProductDetailPage.html?productId=1888" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0">
  #document
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Here is the function I use to append the iframe:

```
(...)

function getBaseUrl() {
    var re = new RegExp(/^.*\//);

    return re.exec(window.location.href);
}

(...)

urlRoot = getBaseUrl()[0];
productLoadedUrl = urlRoot + 'ProductDetailPage.html?productId=' + productId;

(...)

function addIframe() {
    $('<iframe>', {
        src: productLoadedUrl,
        id:  'productDetails',
        class: 'ProductDetailsFrame js-product-details-frame',
        frameborder: 0,
        scrolling: 'yes'
    }).appendTo($body);
}
```